# AutoComplete Typehead in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

There is Typehead i have placed in input text box, which reveal the dropdown of the list. But i want when the user enter any item and which is not available in the list. By clicking Add button it should pop-up "No item"...

Refer to the

[**Code is here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/DtKU4dDYl5pcOAxirUJ5?p=preview)

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate','ui.bootstrap']);


 app.controller('NameCtrl', function ($scope,$http){




     $http.get("lib/data.txt").success(function(res){

  $scope.selected = undefined;
  $scope.states = res;

     });



         $scope.names = [];


        $scope.addName = function() {

if($scope.ww != '' ){

$scope.names.push({
     'x1':$scope.enteredName,
     'qty':$scope.ww,
     'p1':$scope.enteredName.p

    });

 $scope.enteredName = [];
 $scope.ww = '';
 $scope.tp = '';

}
else if ($scope.ww = '')
{

alert("hi");

} else {}




};

















        $scope.removeName = function(name) {
          var i = $scope.names.indexOf(name);
          $scope.names.splice(i, 1);
        };





      $scope.edit = function(name, idx){
        $scope.enteredName = $scope.states.find((item) => item.p === name.p1);
        $scope.sel = name.tp;
        $scope.ww = name.qty;
        $scope.names.splice(idx, 1);
      };


$scope.isCollapsed = true;






      });
```

Comment: I am sorry but I don't quite understand your question. Can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: Hi @LordTribual    I made an application it is simple data entry add/modify and remove function.... so when i start typing in the text box, it gives me the list of the objects from the typehead directive of angularUI but when the obejct what user types is not availble in the list, i want a message should strike as an alret "No item found"

Answer (score 0):

You can add the attribute : typeahead-editable=false 
which will make your ng-model empty if the entry is not in the list. Then you can manage an empty model to add your "No-item" entry.

here is the documentation : (Defaults: true) : Should it restrict model values to the ones selected from the popup only ?

Comment: U are correct sir, but i need an alert box also which say no items....then it make sense